# Scala/Java incompatible Boolean type in spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, boolean

While trying this example from https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-sql-joins.html#joinWith

```
    case class Person(id: Long, name: String, cityId: Long)
    case class City(id: Long, name: String)

    val people = Seq(Person(0, "Agata", 0), Person(1, "Iweta", 0)).toDS
    val cities = Seq(City(0, "Warsaw"), City(1, "Washington")).toDS

    val joined = people.joinWith(cities, people("cityId") === cities("id"))
    joined.show()
```

I am getting this error

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 21, Column 35: Incompatible expression types "boolean" and "java.lang.Boolean"
```

Help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the error is not in the code you have in the question. its somewhere else.

Comment: Could you please add to the listing the import statements (especially implicits) and the way you initialize the `SparkSession`?

Comment: val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val sq = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()

    import sq.implicits._

Comment: I pasted the above into a Spark 2.2.0 `spark-shell` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with Spark version 1.6.0, Scala version 2.10.5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_67) and got

```
scala> val joined = people.joinWith(cities, people("cityId") === cities("id"))
<console>:33: error: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Person] does not take parameters
         val joined = people.joinWith(cities, people("cityId") === cities("id"))
                                                    ^
```

Instead you can try either

```
people.as("p").joinWith(cities.as("c"), $"p.cityId" === $"c.id").show
```

or

```
people.joinWith(cities, people.toDF()("cityId") === cities.toDF()("id")).show
```

or

```
val peopleDF = Seq(Person(0, "Agata", 0), Person(1, "Iweta", 0)).toDF
val citiesDF = Seq(City(0, "Warsaw"), City(1, "Washington")).toDF
peopleDF.join(citiesDF, peopleDF("cityId") === citiesDF("id")).show
```